Show that the equilibrium point of the system $(\dot{x}, \dot{y})=(y,q(t)x)$ is not asymptotically stable
My problem
Let's consider the two-dimensional non-autonomous system
\begin{align}
\frac{dx}{dt}&=y, \\
\frac{dy}{dt}&=q(t)x,
\end{align}
where $q(t)$ is not a constant function and is a continuously differentiable function.
Prove that the zero solution $($i.e.the equilibrium point $(0,0))$ is not asymptotically stable in the Lyapunov sense.
My idea:
I suspect that the zero solution is non-attractive (i.e., the norm of the solution does not tend to zero as $t→+∞$, it is just the definition of the non-attractive in Lyapunov).
And the norm is $x^2+y^2$, from the equations, I obtain a new equation by dividing the two equations as follows:
$$q(t)xdx=ydy
\implies q(t)dx^2=dy^2$$
but I don't know what to do forward. The $q(t)$ is very difficult for me to handle it.
I hope one of you can help me!

It will depend a lot on $q$…

What are initial conditions ?

The function q(t) is not a constant function, and it is continuous and differentiable.

To fix the situation let $q \in C([0, \infty))$.
Assume that $(0,0)$ is asymptotically stable. Since the system is linear then every solution $t \mapsto (x(t),y(t))$ would tend to $(0,0)$ as $t \to \infty$. Now let $(x_1,y_1), (x_2,y_2):[0,\infty) \to \mathbb{R}^{2}$ be a fundamental system of the equation. Since all solutions tend to $(0,0)$ we have $x_1(t)y_2(t)-x_2(t)y_1(t) \to 0$ $(t \to \infty)$. On the other hand check that $(x_1y_2-x_2y_1)'(t) = 0$ $(t \ge 0)$ (the function $x_1y_2-x_2y_1$ is the Wronski-determinant of the fundamental system). Hence
$$
x_1(t)y_2(t)-x_2(t)y_1(t)=x_1(0)y_2(0)-x_2(0)y_1(0) \not=0 \quad (t \ge 0),
$$
a contradiction.
